# Java Swing - JButtons on New Line

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to print out a dynamically generated list of buttons with each button on a new line.

```
public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    //Create the "cards".
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel() {

 JPanel card1 = new JPanel()     
 ... 

int n = 10;
JButton[] jButtons = new JButton[10];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   jButtons[i] = new JButton("test" + i);
   card1.add(jButtons[i]);
   //card1.add("<br>");//<--this is wrong; but hopefully you get my point.
   jButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put them into a box:

```
Box card1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
```

or, if you want all the buttons to have the same size, use GridLayout with one column:

```
JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(n, 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are two solutions using a constrained `GridLayout` and a `BoxLayout`

[image: Dynamic Buttons]

I prefer the `GridLayout` (on the left) since it normalizes the width of the buttons and makes it easy to add a small space between them.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class DynamicButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        final JPanel gridButton = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
        gridButton.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        JPanel gridConstrain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gridConstrain.add(gridButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final Box boxButton = Box.createVerticalBox();
        boxButton.add(new JButton("Button 1"));

        JButton b = new JButton("Add Button");
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            int count = 2;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                gridButton.add(new JButton("Button " + count));

                boxButton.add(new JButton("Button " + count));

                count++;
                gui.revalidate();
            }
        });

        gui.add(b, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(
            JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            new JScrollPane(gridConstrain),
            new JScrollPane(boxButton));
        gui.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,150));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `GridBagLayout` and set `GridBagConstaints.gridy` field.

Comment: GridBagLayout is outdated and too complicated,  I'd advice not to use it in new projects.

Comment: GridBagLayout is maybe outdated, but is more powerfull / clear/ non_buggy than other Custom LayoutManagers +1

Comment: @mKorbel BTW why is it considered outdated? Should we really avoid using it in current swing projects? If so, what's an alternative... ?

Comment: @user3663882 good point, but (if is compared to the MigLayout, TableLayout) GBC and SpringLayout (better alternative, easier and more intuitive) can't works with empty space correctly, (e.g resize of container generating for example situations when is required to divide 10/3, result is empty space in one pixel), in most cases is required to override getPrefferedSize, but answer is upvoted by me, because GUI can be correctly diplayed with little effort

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you need something like this :

[image]

For this you require a [Box Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) , see this for more details :  [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

and if needed here is a demo : [Java Tutorials Code Sample – BoxLayoutDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java)